# Arch Linux: Failed to set locale. Fix your system

Tags: arch-linux, locale

After updating my Arch Linux system yesterday, I started getting an error similar to this:

```
Failed to set locale. Fix your system.
```

This specific error comes from trying to run snapper. However, here is another related error:

```
bsdcpio: Failed to set default locale
```

perl gives a similar warning which I will paste below.

It is not limited to any specific application; it appears to be a system-wide issue.

I did not get these errors prior to yesterday's update. Furthermore, I do not get the errors in a virtual console. I only get them when inside X (KDE). For example I get the error above if I run a snapper ls command in konsole, but I do not get any error if I run the same snapper ls command in a virtual console.

My other Arch systems, which are nearly identical, do not have this issue.

My first attempts at troubleshooting were as follows.

1. check /etc/locale.conf
2. run `locale-gen`
3. check output of `locale`
4. see if snapper runs without an error

I see no errors in locale.conf but running `local-gen` does not resolve the issue.

Here is the relevant output:

```
# localectl list-locales
en_US.utf8

# grep -v "^#" /etc/locale.conf
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

# locale-gen
Generating locales...
en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.

# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

# locale -a
C
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Here's perl's warning:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_COLLATE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MESSAGES = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "en_GB.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
```

The following line appears when I run `locale` inside Konsole (in X), but **not** when I run `locale` in a virtual console:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

I can run the snapper ls command in a virtual console without errors.

As far as I know, Arch doesn't have a `/etc/default/locale`. That file is not present on any of my Arch machines.

Rebooting the system did not help.

Comment: @Fox Generating locale en_GB.UTF-8 did fix it. If you post an answer, I'll accept it. What I don't understand is where `LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8` is being set because `/etc/locale.conf` lists `LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: I found the cause. A user had set the time format to "United Kingdom-British English" in KDE's system settings. Unaware the user had made this change, when I ran the Arch update yesterday, I replaced /etc/locale.gen with the pacnew file and I only enabled en_US.UTF-8. Next time I won't skip the diff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of your locale settings (namely, `LC_TIME`) is set to a locale that you have not generated (namely, `en_GB.UTF-8`).  The error will go away if you enable that locale in `/etc/locale.gen` and regenerate the locales.

Since the setting differs from that set in `/etc/locale.conf`, you may have placed an override in one of your startup scripts.  Since the error does not occur in a virtual console, I suspect `.xinitrc` or `.xprofile`.  However, if you are using a full desktop environment, those often have their own settings, including locale settings.

Answer (score 0):

Another place where override might be present if using KDE (KDE5):

```
./.config/plasma-locale-settings.sh
./.config/plasma-localerc
```

This can be configured in KDE systemsettings.

Basically, if the `locale` output differs from what is configured in `/etc/locale.conf`, it means that some override exists. As Fox answered previously, either missing locales should be enabled in `/etc/locale.gen` and regenerated or `/etc/locale.conf` and any other locale configuration should use whatever locales available in `/etc/locale.gen`.

This also fixes, for example the issue with bsdtar:
`bsdtar: Failed to set default locale`